# Color Overlay on SVG as Background

Tags: css, svg

I'm working with SVG sprites to create an icon system. I'm using [gulp-svg-sprites](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-svg-sprites) to generate the sprites and am using the `symbol` option so when calling each SVG, I can use something as simple as:

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="sprite/svg/symbols.svg#icon-alert"></use></svg>
```

With `fill: currentColor` I'm able to also control the color of each icon, which again, is great.

The issue comes when I need to use these icons as a background element. I'm aware that you cannot use `xlink:href` to grab a specific icon from the sprite -- and am okay just grabbing the individual SVG when needed here, but the issue comes when I need to change the fill/color of that SVG that is referenced as a background image.

Things like `-webkit-background-clip: text;` work great for applying a different background and cutting off based on the text, but I need a solid color overlay that can be switched out on demand.

Is there a simple SVG filter I can attach onto this background (referenced as an SVG) that I can bolt-onto this? Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

## Update

[Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpijt). BUT, I'm looking for something that could also work in IE9, which is why I was hoping for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote an article using a LESS function I wrote that edits the SVG object once its pulled in with LESS http://zslabs.com/articles/svg-background-fill

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter to change the color of the entire element (including the background) - but in most cases you cannot selectively apply it to just the background as you want to. If you had an exact example online with the exact cases you're trying to cover - there may be some very specific solutions for your exact case (eg. if your foreground is all black-stroked, then a color matrix filter could possibly work.))

Comment: Appreciate the answer; if we were to assume the background outside the element was always white, would that help this use-case?

Comment: Added a "sorta kinda" working example, but hoping for **something** that could work down to IE9

Comment: Ah. SVG filters only available in IE10+. Not familiar enough with the dx filters in IE9 to help you. Sorry dude.

Comment: Appreciate the follow-up, was actually able to write a function that directly edits the SVG object once its pulled in with LESS http://zslabs.com/articles/svg-background-fill